# Email validation using CGI script and jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cgi, email-validation

I have CGI script on my server that checks if an email id is in existence. It responds with 'Y' or 'N'. I'm trying to fetch this value on the client side using jquery ajax but I can't seem to get a response. But the script works when I use `CURL`.

Here is my code:
`jQuery.get("http://<mysite-name>/cgi-bin/response.cgi?mailaddress=myid@gmail.com",   function(data){alert(data);})`

The data is null. The response content-type is `text/plain`

I tried even json format. But that didn't seem to work as well.

Comment: can you access ttp://<mysite-name>/cgi-bin/response.cgi?mailaddress=myid@gmail.com in browser?

Comment: yes of course. And I do get a response.

Comment: do you get any errors in javascript console?

Comment: No. There are no errors as such. The status is 200. Here is the headers section of the console `Response Headers
Connection close
Content-Length 2
Content-Type text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date Mon, 17 Dec 2012 04:36:23 GMT
Server Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora)`
`Request Headers
Accept */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Connection keep-alive
Host 192.168.46.150
Origin null
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0`